# What is really a probability distribution?

Tags: probability-theory

I have some difficulties understanding what is difference between *probability measure* and *probability distribution*? I have always thought that term *probability distribution* is reserved for measure on a state space of some random variable (therefore on Borel sets). But some sources define *probability distribution* even without refering to random variables. So in that case is there any difference between those two terms? I am very puzzled.

If, for example, I have probability space $\Omega=\{a,b,c,d\}, \mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}, p(a)=p(b)=p(c)=p(d)=\frac{1}{4}$, then can I call probability measure $p$ a probability distribution on $\Omega$?

What if $\mathcal{F}=\{\Omega, \emptyset\}$, so that $\mathcal{F}\ne \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$?

Comment: You can use the expressions "probability measure" and "probability distribution" in lieu of each other. The "cdf" or _cumulative distribution function_ refers to a special way of describing the probability measure. Or there is the "pmf" the _probability mass function_ (in the case of discrete distributions) which is another way of describing a measure.

Comment: A measure is always given on a $\sigma$-algebra. If the measure is given on a larger $\sigma$-algebra then it is given on the smaller one as well.

Comment: What does $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ denote?

Comment: In that case $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)=2^{\Omega}$ (family of borel sets under discrete topology)

Comment: In case of random variable, any probability measure can be viewed as the distribution of the identity function. so there is no formal differences. it is rather how you view them.

Comment: In the context of probability you can think of a measure as being a probability distribution over a set $\Omega$.  Since a random variable $X$ is a function whose domain is $\Omega$, this translates to a probability distribution over the *range* of $X$.

Comment: @dsaxton "In the context of probability you can think of a measure as being a probability distribution over a set Ω" Well, no. Actually, a key-insight since at least Kolmogorov is that probability measures are defined on *sigma-algebras*.